# How to prevent default action of space bar except inside inputs?

Tags: jquery, html

By default, when we press a space bar key over `document` it scrolls down. To prevent the default behaviour, we could do the following :

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

But we cannot do the above, when we have certain input fields, for it will not allow us to type into the text fields.

How could I prevent the default action of space bar, without infringing the rights of others!

Comment: Your code is also likely to break other things (such as using the tab key to navigate around the page) so you should be more discriminatory about when you prevent the default action (i.e. check it is actually the space bar that was pressed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

1. Check `event.target` to see if it is an input element and not prevent default if it is *or*
2. Bind event handlers to the input elements which [stop propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

I'd just not break normal scrolling features in the first place though.

Comment: I need to pause and play a video from a space bar press. That is the reason I have to break the default behavior

Comment: @SuhailGupta — Normally you'd only do that if the video had the focus

Comment: I need to constantly pause and play the video. I had to bind this event to the document.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. Apparently here is how I solved it:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (
        ['input', 'textarea', 'select', 'button']
        .indexOf(document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase()) == -1
    ) {
        // Current focused element is NOT an input. Let's prevent scroll!
        event.preventDefault();
        // Now we can do various stuff.
    } else {
        // User is typing something into a focused input.
        // Do NOT do anything here.
    }
}
```